# Hierarchical Gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview, datagrid

I need to bind hierarchical List object to a Gridview (Hierarchical in windows form).  How can this be achieved - any examples ??

Ex: of list object

List of CargoMovement => Cargomovents 
and each CargoMovement has List of Transactions

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think there is a standard way of doing data binding for hierarchical data.  There are a lot of [tree grids from 3rd party vendors](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=winform+tree+grid) that may help you.

*Lot depends on the "shape of the data" you wish to display, so you may wish to get a more general question that explains the shape of your data and asks how to display it.*

Answer (score 0):

There is an [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx) at MSDN that gives a description as well as example code on how it can be done.